# There was an error deserializing the object of type .Pages.Response. '� PVT LTD' contains invalid UTF8 bytes

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        throw new Exception(String.Format(
        "Server errOr (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
        response.StatusCode,
        response.StatusDescription));
    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Clari5AppWeb.Pages.Response));
    object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
    Response jsonResponse = objResponse as Response;
    return jsonResponse;
```

Please solve it; only for some search values it gives an error.

Comment: The most obvious thing to check is if you actually have an UTF8 stream. Did you request the server to serve data with that encoding? It's not default.

Comment: Thanks in adv.  How to check UTF8 stream? how to request the server with encoded data? please help me wtih code level.